# Getting an error while trying to access javascript from a java class

Tags: javascript, java, scriptengine

I hava a JavaScript file with a function that looks like this:

```
function getid() {
    var e = document.getElementById("identity");
    var iden = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;    
    return iden;
}
```

and I am trying to use the JavaScript using the following code:

```
public ResultSet Getsname() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{  
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    // read script file
    try {
        engine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("C:/Users/Sony/workspace/StudentRegiForm/WebContent/ValidateMark.js"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (ScriptException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
    // call function from script file
    Integer uid= null;
    try {
        uid = (Integer) inv.invokeFunction("getid()");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | ScriptException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error when I execute:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such function getid()

Comment: Try with `getid` (without the parentheses)

Comment: If I remove the () I get another exception javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined in <eval> . That makes sense because that's a browser defined variable. How can you get the document and an element if the JavaScript is not executed on a web page?

Comment: Your JS code does not make much sense, there is no "document" when it is executed through the JavaScript engine. What do you want to do?

Comment: what i actually want to do is when someone selects an id i want the selected id  to be stored in var iden and then when i invoke the javascript from the function GetsName i get the selected id which i use in a query to retrieve the name corresponding to that id

Comment: its not executing the document.getElementById("identity");

Comment: It _can't_ execute document.getElementById because there is no document. I think you are mis-using the JavaScript engine. It is not supposed to replace a browser.

Comment: what should i do ??? should i use a webEngine?? can you please help me out with this??

Comment: I am sorry but I really don't understand what you want to do here. What is the big picture? What do you want? Do you want to make a web-page?

Comment: yes i am making a web page containing a marks form.. i have created a jsp page which holds the form...there i have a id selects box populated by values from my database....i want that when some one selects an id the corresponding name is retrieved from the database and populate the name field in the form

Comment: how do i send you the code for all of this??

Comment: That's what I figured and that's why I said you are mis-using the JavaScript Engine. It is not a browser. The webpage is on the client side. Your Java is on the server side. You can call the server side from the client side by making HTTP requests (GET or POST). I suggest you read a tutorial on web developement so you can understand better what it is about and how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
uid = (Integer) inv.invokeFunction("getid()");
```

to

```
uid = (Integer) inv.invokeFunction("getid");
```

I would be careful as well casting to `Integer` better to use `Object` and then do 
`if (uid instanceof Integer)`...

so

```
  Object uid = null

  uid =  inv.invokeFunction("getid");

  if (uid instanceof Integer){
     system.out.println("ok");
  }
```

Comment: If I remove the () I get another exception javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined in <eval> . That makes sense because that's a browser defined variable. How can you get the document and an element if the JavaScript is not executed on a web page?